# Expect sub Methods to throw an error when parent method throws an error in JEST

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, firebase-authentication, jestjs

- Inside the method `signup` , I am mocking
  `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword` and making it throw
  an `error`
- So now i expect that the parent method i.e `signup` should also throw since a `sub-method` of the `signup` method has thrown an error
- But test cases are failing , What am i missing here ?

**App.js**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'
import './Init'

const App = {
  firebase: firebase,
  signup: async (email, password) => {
    const userCredential = await App.firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    await userCredential.user.sendEmailVerification()
    return `Check your email for verification mail before logging in`
  },
export default App
```

**App.spec.ts**

```
import myAuthenticationPlugin from 'authenticationPlugin/App'
it('to Throw',async ()=>{
     myAuthenticationPlugin.firebase = {
     auth: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
     createUserWithEmailAndPassword: jest.fn(() => {
       throw new Error('Network Error')
     }),
   }
     expect(myAuthenticationPlugin.firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword).toThrowError('Network Error')
     expect(await myAuthenticationPlugin.signup).toThrow() // THIS FAILS
    })
```

**Error**

```
 expect(received).toThrow()

    Received function did not throw

      107 |       expect(myAuthenticationPlugin.firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword).toThrowError('Network Error')
    > 108 |       expect(await myAuthenticationPlugin.signup).toThrow()
          |                                                   ^
      109 | 
      110 |     })
      111 |   })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has a few problems:

```
expect(await myAuthenticationPlugin.signup).toThrow() // THIS FAILS
```

First of all, the parameter passed to `expect` must be a function, so this is *almost* correct:

```
expect(async () => { await myAuthenticationPlugin.signup() }).toThrow()
```

...but it also won't work. That's because the `.toThrow()` function is for detecting synchronous error throwing, not for checking for rejected Promises. You'll want to use [`.rejects`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#rejects) to tell Jest to unwrap the Promise instead:

```
await expect(myAuthenticationPlugin.signup()).rejects.toThrow()
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your expertise helped me greatly, Solved my problem and helped me learn about how jest works internally :)

Comment: thanks a lot Jacob. @Phil FYI you can also check for the error message itself, like:

test('checks that the newUserCreated function throws', async () => {
    // Create a Database snapshot
    const snap = testEnv.database.makeDataSnapshot({
      id: testUserId,
      firstName: 'Dan Pralea'
    }, testUserPath);
    
    await expect(wrapped(snap)).rejects.toThrowError('Cannot read property \'make\' of undefined');
  });